# Install custom component package in Orchard custom module in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

I have created one module called HellowWorls, i need to install custom nuget packages in this module and need to refer some custom script files.

How to do it?
Any help?

Thanks,

Comment: Just open it in visual studio and install some nuget packages??

Comment: i have opened my module in VS and try install, nuget not installed show some error, solution file not found..

Comment: Open the Orchard.sln, not just your module project

Comment: I tried with orchard solution file also, nuget is installed but orchard become not working

Comment: Include screenshots/errors what isn't working, we cannot help you with this short description

Comment: That package is custom HTML helper package, is this possible to add custom html helper in orchard CMS?